# Dynamically loading a java library

Tags: java

I want to load all the code straight to memory from a link without having to actually download it and store it.
I have tried looking it up, but I've only found ways to compile a class using strings.

Would it even be possible to make that?

Comment: You can create a special classloader that fetches class files over the network. See this for a starting point: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41963273/how-to-use-classloader-to-load-class-file-from-server-to-client. 
Also you can fetch a string (a Java file) and compile it to executable code with something like Javassit. Pick your poison.

Comment: @DanielVoina Will, that include other imported classes or do I have to manually include all of them?

Comment: You mean transitively loaded? Any class you want to use directly or indirectly should be fetched and loaded in the VM